# Unable to check a checkbox on a Silverlight web app using Ranorex automation

Tags: c#, silverlight, ranorex

I am creating a `Ranorex Checkbox` object and then grabbing the appropriate checkbox using `Ranorexpath`. But I am unable to check this checkbox using the `CheckBox.Check()` event. On the UI, a tick mark appears on the checkbox but in reality the checkbox remains unchecked and as a result the expected messages do not appear on the screen and the test fails. Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Code snipped below:

```
                if(value=="99283" || value =="99281")
                {
                    Ranorex.CheckBox EMlevelReason="/dom[@domain='"+domain+"']//object[#'slApp']/form/form[1]/form/list[@automationid='lstOuter']/listitem[4]/list/listitem[4]/checkbox[@name='Single xray']";                      
                    EMlevelReason.Focus();                     
                    if(EMlevelReason.Checked!=true)
                    {
                        EMlevelReason.Focus();
                        EMlevelReason.Check();  // doesn't work. the checkbox appears checked on the UI but actually remains unchecked                  
                    }
                }
```

Comment: What does your code look like..? also have you checked the Ranorex website for code samples and examples..?http://www.ranorex.com/search.html?q=Ranorex+Checkbox the second link will help you more perhaps http://www.ranorex.com/support/user-guide-20/ranorexpath.html

Comment: @DJKRAZE I have got the ranorexpath right... Like I mentioned it able to focus on the checkbox. But is unable to check it.

Comment: Perhaps you should post the code method or event where the code resides where you are checking the State of the CheckBox..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to develop a workaround for this. We used the `click()` event instead of `check()`
i.e. in the above code we just replaced `EMlevelReason.Check()` with `EMlevelReason.Click()`
Don't know why but it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think that it was not checked even though it was shown as checked?
It sounds like a script is normally executed when the checkbox is checked, if so you could try the following code:

```
Mouse.Click(EMlevelReason);
```